# Website background doesn't fill with display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css

As it is right now, I have some sections of my website that have `style="display:none;"` in the code. Some of the buttons on my website run Javascript that show those, `$('#phonecompText').fadeIn();`. When I let the lines of text on my site fadein, the background does not keep up with the page.

Before
[image: Website without thing shown - Default]

[image: Website once a few items fadein]

Any idea on how I can have the background stretch down?

These are the files in my css folder.
[image: CSS Folder]

And here is my [style.css](http://pastebin.com/UzbxMNWR)

```css
   

@charset 'UTF-8';
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic,700|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700");
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Basic                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/
body {
 background-color: #dbdbdb;
 background-image: url('images/bg02.png');
}
body.is-loading * {
 -moz-transition: none !important;
 -webkit-transition: none !important;
 -o-transition: none !important;
 -ms-transition: none !important;
 transition: none !important;
 -moz-animation: none !important;
 -webkit-animation: none !important;
 -o-animation: none !important;
 -ms-animation: none !important;
 animation: none !important;
}
body, input, textarea, select {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #565656;
}
a {
 color: #1784CD;
}
strong, b {
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #232323;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #232323;
}
h2 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}
blockquote {
 border-left: solid 5px #ddd;
 padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
 font-style: italic;
}
em, i {
 font-style: italic;
}
hr {
 border: 0;
 border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
 padding: 1.5em 0 0 0;
 margin: 1.75em 0 0 0;
}
sub {
 position: relative;
 top: 0.5em;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}
sup {
 position: relative;
 top: -0.5em;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}
br.clear {
 clear: both;
}
p, ul, ol, dl, table {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
/* Table */
 
table {
 width: 100%;
}
table.default {
}
table.default tbody tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
 background: #f4f4f4;
}
table.default td {
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
}
table.default th {
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 0.75em 1em 0.75em 1em;
}
table.default thead {
 border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}
table.default tfoot {
 border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
 background: #eee;
}
table.default tbody {
}
/* Form */
  
form {
}
form label {
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #232323;
 margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}
form input[type="text"],  form input[type="email"],  form input[type="password"],  form select,  form textarea {
 display: block;
 border-radius: 0.4em;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border: solid 1px #ddd;
 padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 1.25em;
}
form input[type="text"]:focus,  form input[type="email"]:focus,  form input[type="password"]:focus,  form select:focus,  form textarea:focus {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #1784CD;
}
 form ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #aaa;
}
 form :-moz-placeholder {
 color: #aaa;
}
 form ::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #aaa;
}
 form :-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #aaa;
}
/* Section/Article */
 
header {
 margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
header > p {
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 1em;
 color: #999;
}
section,  article {
 margin-bottom: 3em;
}
section > :last-child,  article > :last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
section > .inner > :last-child,  article > .inner > :last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
section:last-child,  article:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* Image */

.image {
 display: inline-block;
}
.image img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.image.fit {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.image.featured {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
.image.left {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
}
.image.centered {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
.image.centered img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: auto;
}
/* Button */

{
display: none;
}
input[type="button"],  input[type="submit"],  input[type="reset"],  .button {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #1784CD;
 background-image: url('images/bg01.png');
 border-radius: 0.4em;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-decoration: none;
 -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(59,0,0,0.5);
}
input[type="button"]:disabled,  input[type="submit"]:disabled,  input[type="reset"]:disabled,  input[type="button"].disabled,  input[type="submit"].disabled,  input[type="reset"].disabled,  .button.disabled {
 opacity: 0.35;
 cursor: default;
}
input[type="button"]:hover,  input[type="submit"]:hover,  input[type="reset"]:hover,  .button:hover {
 background-color: #289eed;
}
input[type="button"]:active,  input[type="submit"]:active,  input[type="reset"]:active,  .button:active {
 background-color: #b93653;
}
input[type="button"].alt,  input[type="submit"].alt,  input[type="reset"].alt,  .button.alt {
 background-color: #364050;
}
input[type="button"].alt:hover,  input[type="submit"].alt:hover,  input[type="reset"].alt:hover,  .button.alt:hover {
 background-color: #465060;
}
input[type="button"].alt:active,  input[type="submit"].alt:active,  input[type="reset"].alt:active,  .button.alt:active {
 background-color: #263040;
}
/* List */
 
ul.default {
 list-style: disc;
 padding-left: 1em;
}
ul.default li {
 padding-left: 0.5em;
}
ol.default {
 list-style: decimal;
 padding-left: 1.25em;
}
ol.default li {
 padding-left: 0.25em;
}
/* Pagination */

.pagination {
}
.pagination .pages {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.pagination .pages span {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 0.4em 0 0;
}
.pagination .pages a {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
 background-color: #dbdbdb;
 background-image: url('images/bg02.png');
 color: #565656;
 margin: 0 0.4em 0 0;
 border-radius: 0.4em;
 -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0.075em 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.pagination .pages a:hover {
 background-color: #dadada;
}
.pagination .pages a.active {
 background-color: #364050;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: none;
 text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
/* Box */

.box {
}
.box.calendar {
}
.box.calendar .inner {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #272E39;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 border-radius: 0.4em;
 padding: 0.75em 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05), inset 0 0 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.box.calendar caption {
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 0 0.25em 0;
}
.box.calendar table {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.box.calendar tr {
}
.box.calendar td,  .box.calendar th {
 cursor: default;
 padding: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0;
 border-top: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.075);
}
.box.calendar th {
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fff;
}
.box.calendar td a,  .box.calendar td span {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1.5em;
 height: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 border-radius: 0.4em;
 -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.box.calendar td a {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.box.calendar td a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(200,225,255,0.1);
 color: #fff;
}
.box.calendar td.today a {
 background-color: #1784CD;
 background-image: url('images/bg01.png');
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15), 0 0.025em 0.15em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 color: #fff !important;
}
.box.post {
 position: relative;
}
.box.post .info {
}
.box.post .info .stats {
 margin: 0;
 cursor: default;
}
.box.post .info .stats a {
 font-size: 0.8em;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #232323;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 1em;
}
.box.recent-posts,  .box.recent-comments {
}
.box.recent-posts li,  .box.recent-comments li {
 border-top: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.075);
 padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
}
.box.recent-posts li:first-child,  .box.recent-comments li:first-child {
 border-top: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 padding-top: 0;
}
.box.recent-posts li:last-child,  .box.recent-comments li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
.box.search {
}
.box.search form {
 position: relative;
}
.box.search form input {
 position: relative;
 padding-right: 34px;
}
.box.search form:before {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 content: '\f002';
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0, mirror=1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
 -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
 -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
 -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
 transform: scale(-1, 1);
 position: absolute;
 right: 0.5em;
 top: 0.25em;
 z-index: 1;
 text-shadow: none;
 color: #c8ccce;
}
.box.text-style1 {
}
.box.text-style1 .inner {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #272E39;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 border-radius: 0.4em;
 padding: 1.25em;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05), inset 0 0 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Wrapper                                                                       */
/*********************************************************************************/

#wrapper {
 position: relative;
}
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Nav                                                                           */
/*********************************************************************************/

#nav {
}
#nav > ul > li > ul {
 display: none;
}
#nav ul {
 margin: 0;
}
#nav li {
 border-top: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.075);
 padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
}
#nav li:first-child {
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 padding-top: 0;
}
#nav li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
#nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.4em 1em 0.4em 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-radius: 0.4em;
 outline: 0;
 -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
}
#nav li.current a {
 background-color: #272E39 !important;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) !important;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05), inset 0 0 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fff;
}
#nav li:hover a {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 color: #fff;
}
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Sidebar                                                                       */
/*********************************************************************************/

#sidebar {
 color: #aaa;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.55);
 text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#sidebar form input,  #sidebar form select,  #sidebar form textarea {
 border: 0;
}
#sidebar section,  #sidebar nav {
 position: relative;
}
#sidebar section:before,  #sidebar nav:before {
 content: '';
 border-top: solid 1px;
 border-bottom: solid 1px;
 border-color: #171E29;
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.075), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.075);
 display: block;
}
#sidebar strong, #sidebar b {
 color: #fff;
}
#sidebar a {
 color: #d4dde0;
}
#sidebar h2,  #sidebar h3,  #sidebar h4,  #sidebar h5,  #sidebar h6 {
 color: #fff;
}
#sidebar header {
 margin: 0 0 1.25em 0;
}
#sidebar section,  #sidebar nav {
 margin: 2em 0 0 0;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}
#sidebar section:before,  #sidebar nav:before {
 height: 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Content                                                                       */
/*********************************************************************************/
  
#content {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 background-image: url('images/bg02.png');
}
#content > .inner {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Mobile UI                                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

#titleBar {
 background: #364050 url('images/bg01.png');
}
#titleBar .title {
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 44px;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 text-align: center;
}
#titleBar .toggle {
 width: 80px;
 height: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
#titleBar .toggle:before {
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 content: '\f0c9';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 7px;
 top: 7px;
 font-size: 14px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 background: #1784CD url('images/bg01.png');
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15), 0 0.025em 0.15em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#titleBar .toggle:active {
}
#titleBar .toggle:active:before {
 background-color: #289eed;
}
#sidePanel {
 background: #364050 url('images/bg01.png');
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>     

<body class="left-sidebar">
  <!-- Wrapper -->
  <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content">
      <div class="inner">

        <!-- Post -->
        <article class="box post post-excerpt">
          <header>
            <!--
Note: Titles and subtitles will wrap automatically when necessary, so don't worry
if they get too long. You can also remove the <p> entirely if you don't
                                                                                        need a subtitle.
                                                                                -->
            <nav class="cl-effect-1">
              <h2><a href="textbomber.php">Start Below</a></h2>
            </nav>
            <p>Guests can only send 4 texts at a time</p>
            <p><a href="register.php">Register for more texts</a>
            </p>
            <p id='sentText'></p>
          </header>
          <div class="info" style="background-color:#F2F2F2;">
           
            <ul class="stats">
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=Check%20out%20OtherTXT.com%20!" class="icon fa-twitter">2521</a> 
              </li>
              <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=OtherTXT.com" class="icon fa-facebook">128</a> 
                <br>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <span class="input input--juro">
        <input class="input__field input__field--juro" name="phonenum" maxlength="15" type="text" id="phonenum" required/>
        <label class="input__label input__label--juro" for="phonenum"> <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--juro">Phone Number: (10 Digit Phone Number if USA)</span> 
          </label>
          </span>
          <br>

          <form>
            <select name="provider" required>
              <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Phone Company</option>
              <option value="@txt.att.net">AT&amp;T</option>
              <option value="@myboostmobile.com">Boost Mobile</option>
              <option value="@sms.mycricket.com">Cricket Wireless</option>
              <option value="@mymetropcs.com">MetroPCS</option>
              <option value="@messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint</option>
              <option value="@message.ting.com">Ting</option>
              <option value="@tmomail.net">T-Mobile</option>
              <option value="@pxail.uscc.net">U.S. Cellular</option>
              <option value="@vtext.com">Verizon</option>
              <option value="otherprovider">Other</option>
            </select>
          </form>

          <span class="input input--juro">
        <input class="input__field input__field--juro hideother" name="otherprov" type="text" id="otherprov" style="display: block;">
        <label class="input__label input__label--juro" for="otherprov"> <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--juro hideother" id="other" style="display: block;">Other:</span> 
          </label>
          </span>

          <form>
            <input type="button" class="whattoput hideother" id="whattoput" name="whattoput" value="What to put?" />
            <a class="hideother" style="display:none;">
              <br>
              <br>
            </a>
            <strong id="phonecompText" style="direction:none;"></strong>
            <input type="button" name="otherlistbut" class="important-btn" value="I don't know the phone company." />
            <!--    <p>
         <h3>Subject:</h3>
         <input type="text" value="OtherTXT.com" disabled/>
         </p> -->


            <h3>Message:</h3>
            <textarea name="message" rows="3" id="message" required></textarea>
            <h3>Amount:</h3>
            <input name="amount" id="amount" type="number" max="4" value="0" />
            <h3>Seconds Between Texts:</h3>
            <input name="time" type="number" min="1" value="1" required disabled/>
            <strong id=sentamountText style="display:none;"></strong>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="sendtxt" value="Start Sending" />
            <p>By submitting a number through OtherTXT, you assume and take full responsibility for any result of the sending of the messages.</p>
          </form>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">

      <!-- Logo -->
      <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.php">OtherTXT</a></h1>
      <!-- Nav -->
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="login.php">Login / Register</a> 
          </li>
          <li class="current"><a href="textbomber.php">Text Bomber</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="tools.php">Tools</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="packages.php">Packages</a>
          </li>
          <!-- <li><a href="raffle.php">Raffle</a></li> -->

          <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Me</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="tos.php">TOS / Privacy Policy</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="JJ9REYLJG5ZZW">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Donate">
              <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

     
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {



      $("#whattoput").hide();
      $("#otherprov").hide();
      $("#other").hide();
      $('#calender').load('calender.html');

      var d = new Date();
      var dayofMonth = d.getDate();
      $("#" + dayofMonth).addClass('today');


    });

    $('input[name="whattoput"]').click(function() {
      window.open("http://othertxt.com/provlist.php");
    });


    $('select[name="provider"]').change(function() {
      showhideOther();
    });

    $('input[name="otherlistbut"]').click(function(d) {
      if ($("#phonenum").val() === "") {
        $('#phonecompText').fadeIn();
        document.getElementById('phonecompText').innerHTML = "Please enter the phone number first.<br>";
      } else {
        lookupProvider(d);
      }
    });

    $('input[name="sendtxt"]').click(function(e) {
      if ($("#phonenum").val() === "3108667738") {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.replace("https://othertxt.com/ArieIsHot.html");
      } else {
        if ($("#phonenum").val() === "") {
          document.getElementById("phonenum").style.borderColor = "red";
        } else if ($("#message").val() === "") {
          document.getElementById("message").style.borderColor = "red";
        } else if ($("#amount").val() === "0") {
          document.getElementById("amount").style.borderColor = "red";
        } else {
          document.getElementById('sentamountText').innerHTML = '<br>Sending...<br>You may leave this page.<br>';
          $("#sentamountText").fadeIn();
          sendText(e);
        }
      }
      if ($("#amount").val() > 4) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You must register to send more than 4 texts");
      }
    });


    /************ FUNCTIONS ******************/
    $('input[name="phonenum"],input[name="amount"],input[name="time"]').on('input', function() {
      if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      }
    });

    function showhideOther() {
      if ($('select[name="provider"]').val() == "otherprovider") {
        $(".hideother").fadeIn();
      } else {
        $(".hideother").fadeOut();
      }
    }




    function lookupProvider(d) {
      $('#phonecompText').fadeIn();
      document.getElementById('phonecompText').innerHTML = "Loading...<br>";
      d.preventDefault();
      var phonenum = $('input[name="phonenum"]').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          phonenum: phonenum
        },
        url: 'prov.php',
        success: function(data) { //Receives the data from the php code
          document.getElementById('phonecompText').innerHTML = "Phone Company: " + data + "<br>";

        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
          console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
          console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    }

    function sendText(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("phonenum").style.borderColor = "initial";
      document.getElementById("message").style.borderColor = "initial";
      document.getElementById("amount").style.borderColor = "initial";
      var phonenum = $('input[name="phonenum"]').val();
      var provider = $('select[name="provider"]').val();
      var message = $('textarea[name="message"]').val();
      var otherprov = $('input[name="otherprov"]').val();
      var amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
      var time = $('input[name="time"]').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          provider: provider,
          message: message,
          phonenum: phonenum,
          amount: amount,
          otherprov: otherprov,
          time: time
        },
        url: 'send.php',
        success: function(data) {
          document.getElementById('sentamountText').innerHTML = '<br>Sent ' + amount + ' texts.<br>';
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
          console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
          console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
      });

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: height: 100vh bro always

Comment: @Tambo Haha, thanks. So I should go into my style.css and add that in there, right?

Comment: yes ^^. add it to your container's class.

Comment: @jbutler483 I legit tried adding it to every container class I saw and still no go. http://pastebin.com/CqzWzXfT

Comment: @pshyoulost: could you post your right-hand-side markup (i.e the main part) in your question?

Comment: @jbutler483 I updated my question. I know that's probably not what you're asking me to do but I don't understand your question. Sorry =/ I'm a bit retarded lol

Comment: To me this looks like a standard "container does not wrap around floats"-problem. Try to apply a standard clearfix solution to the surrounding container which you want to "stretch":

`.surrounding_container:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}`

Comment: @pshyoulost: could you post your html as well? I can then edit for you

Comment: A background image has no relative height, so will only display correctly if the element your adding it too has a height applied.

Comment: @connexo I threw that into my skel.css and no go =/

Comment: @jbutler483 I'm not exactly sure what you did with the edit. Is that the fixed code? I'm a bit confuzzled

Comment: Please post only the relevant parts of the html, css and js. And please use jsfiddle.

Comment: @pshyoulost: that's a **snippet** it should be used as part of your question. It's not fixed, it's just a way of showing **your current code**

Comment: I've put in it a fiddle, but it looks just as crappy and screwed as it does here when you "Run snippet".

http://jsfiddle.net/connexo/ans36cx3/

Comment: @connexo That's because it's missing a bunch of stuff. I tried fixing it in jsfiddle and I couldn't get it to look right. I'd be more than happy to give one of you guys FTP access =O

Comment: Just a guess, add `overflow:hidden` to whatever element isn't expanding like it should be.

Comment: @David I tried that and it didn't work :(

Comment: Where did you add it?